# Is the log in the simplified gradient equation a $\log_{10}$ or a $\log_e$?

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis

I am trying to understand how does [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/uh1Dk68cfWs?t=1004) simplifies the gradient equation ($\nabla f(x) + u\nabla g(x)=0)$ with the KKT conditions. Indeed, according to the Youtuber:

$$\nabla f(x)+\frac{-t}{g(x)} \nabla g(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow \nabla (f(x)-t\log(-g(x))=0$$

Indeed when derivating $\nabla (f(x)-t\log(-g(x))$ it is equivalent to

\begin{align}
\nabla f(x)-t \left(-\nabla g(x) \frac{1}{-g(x)\ln 10}\right) &=0 \ as \ \log(u)'=\frac{u'(x)}{u(x)\ln 10}
\end{align}

This comes from

[image]

Then it would rather be:

$$\Leftrightarrow\nabla f(x)-t \left( \frac{
\nabla g(x)}{g(x)\ln 10}\right) =0$$

Unless I assume that $\log(x)$ is in fact $\log_e(x)$, isn't it? So what should I assume?

Thanks! I am a slow learner in mathematics, don't hesitate to explain it to me as if I was a teenager.

Comment: Whether the natural logarithm is denoted log or ln depends on what branch of mathematics you are working in and, I think, in what country you went to school. So I would not get too fixated on there being one universal way. In optimization log would normally mean log base $e$.

Comment: In the vast majority of higher mathematics, $\log$ means base $e$.

Comment: For base $e$ , the notation "ln" would be better since the danger of misunderstanding is much smaller. Although "lg" usually denotes the decadical and "log" the natural logarithm, it would be best if the base is displayed (unless it is $e$) to avoid any misunderstandings.